# Is it acceptable to have Replication factor 3 for a 3 node cluster in Cassandra with Consistency level as LOCAL_ONE in multi datacenter?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

We have 2 Datacenters each having 3 nodes with replication factor of 3 for each Datacenter (Total 6 replicas) with read consistency level as LOCAL_ONE. Since we are not using LOCAL_QUORUM or DC_LOCAL_QUORUM, is it acceptable to go with 3 nodes in each datacenter?

Can anyone suggest the best Consistency level for read operation with the current configuration in order to get the latest information across the datacenters?

```
Configuration:
Solr DC1 : 3 nodes, RF=3
Solr DC2 : 3 nodes, RF=3
Versions:
dse 4.8.3
cassandra 2.1.11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having three nodes per datacemter and RF=3 in each is not unreasonable - it allows you to have durability and HA in either/both datacenters.

The consistency level will depend on your business requirements - do you need strong consistency? What should happen if the datacenters cannot communicate? Your consistency and availability requirements should dictate your consistency level.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we want the data to be consistent across the datacenters and need strong consistency. It's sure that  we will get stale data when queried for read operation with Consistency Level - ONE or LOCAL_ONE. Can you give me your feedback on this?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to make sure you use EACH_QUORUM on writes. Doing so will allow you to read with LOCAL_QUORUM on reads (lowering your latency costs there). Alternatively, you could read with QUORUM (which would require a DC round trip), but that doesn't gain much in theory.